# Docker nginx reverse proxy not load static file

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-lightsail, cadvisor

I am working on a project with AWS LIghtsail container and I am facing with the following problem.

I created 3 docker containers:

-NGINX port 80
-NodeJs port 5000
-Cadvisor port 8080

Lightsail container service allows you to have only one port open from which you can reach your resources, for this reason I used nginx proxy pass to make all my containers reachable on port 80.

My problem is that when I try to reach $host/containers it does not load static resources (CSS, JS, images....).

These are my nginx configs

```
events {}

http {
     upstream node {
         server  ${NODE_HOST}:${NODE_PORT};
         }
      upstream cad {
          server ${CAD_HOST}:${CAD_PORT};
          }

      server {
         listen 80;

           #proxy pass nodejs works  
           location / {
                proxy_pass http://node;
                      }

           #proxy pass cadvisor port8080 not work
           location /containers/ {
                proxy_pass http://cad;
                
    }
}
 }
```

```
#EV VAR

NGINX_ENVSUBST_OUTPUT_DIR=/etc/nginx
NODE_HOST=node
NODE_PORT=5000
CAD_HOST=cad
CAD_PORT=8080
```

I was following this AWS official guide (step 5): https://aws.amazon.com/it/getting-started/hands-on/setup-an-nginx-reverse-proxy/

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eneU1.png)

Comment: check your logs first, then I see that you use `proxy_redirect` directive incorrectly, basically you don't need it. Simple `alias` might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
http {

    upstream node {
        server ${NODE_HOST}:${NODE_PORT};
    }

    upstream cad {
        server ${CAD_HOST}:${CAD_PORT};
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://node;
        }

        location @cad {
            proxy_pass http://cad;
        }

        location /docker/ {
            alias /cadvisor/docker/;
        }

        location /containers/ {
            alias /cadvisor/containers/;

            try_files $uri $uri/ @cad;
        }
    }

}
```

and check your logs after

Comment: These are the logs with your snippet configs:




nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx_1  | 2022/04/15 16:59:51 [emerg] 1#1: duplicate location "/containers/" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:25
nginx_1  | nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/containers/" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:25

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Anyway it does not work

Comment: @MarcoDondo uh, sorry, I've messed up with 2 identical locations, I've edited my answer, please check it

Comment: Nope. With your new correction snippet It returns HTTP 500. Here the nginx log--->
nginx_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2022:12:45:28 +0000] "GET /containers/ HTTP/1.1" 500 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36"

Comment: With my configs in the question it returns 200 but it only loads the html. The css, js and the images are not served.

Comment: @MarcoDondo, 500 error is too ambiguous, what is in `error.log`, not access one? It might be script or permissions, might be nginx configuration, you name it.

Comment: 2022/04/19 10:49:35 [error] 36#36: *7 could not find named location "@cad", client: x.x.x.x, server: , request: "GET /containers/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Comment: @MarcoDondo, ok, I've changed my answer, please try new config

Comment: with this new configs I get the same problem as previously:HTML is loaded, but static file are not loaded.

Comment: check the screenshot in the question

Comment: @MarcoDondo It is better to watch logs for actual paths being requested by browser, I can not get anything from your screenshot. You need to know where nginx is actually watching for your static files.